# Check that an array includes at least a set of values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

How can I check that the `$courseAreas` array includes *at least* "ayrshire" 
and "fife"?

I've tried the following code, but it does not work:

```
$courseAreas = array('ayrshire', 'fife', 'cheshire', 'lanarkshire');
$includesAyrshireAndFife = (count(array_intersect(array('ayrshire', 'fife'), $courseAreas)) >= 2 ? true : false);
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine? What exactly "does not work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$courseAreas = array('ayrshire', 'fife', 'cheshire', 'lanarkshire');
$includesAyrshireAndFife = count(array_intersect(array('ayrshire', 'fife'), $courseAreas)) > 1;
```

You don't even need tenary operator because with > it's already boolean expression.

**Edit**:

I've noticed that your code works too. I've just shorten it.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the `? true : false` outside the braces

```
$courseAreas = array('ayrshire', 'fife', 'cheshire', 'lanarkshire');
$includesAyrshireAndFife = (count(array_intersect(array('ayrshire', 'fife'), $courseAreas)) >= 2) ? true : false;
var_dump($includesAyrshireAndFife);

$courseAreas = array('ayrshire', 'stirlingshire', 'cheshire', 'lanarkshire');
$includesAyrshireAndFife = (count(array_intersect(array('ayrshire', 'fife'), $courseAreas)) >= 2) ? true : false;
var_dump($includesAyrshireAndFife);
```

[Seems to work](https://3v4l.org/3hKlT)

But your original also seems to work perfectly well.... in what circumstances do you find that it fails?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in_array()`

See :- http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp